# TypeError:undefined is not a function(evaluating 'store.getState()')

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have worked on react 16.6.3 with redux for passing parameters within components and send file data to backend.
I added reducers.js,actions.js,store.js and added those to my components but it generate error undefined is not a function(evaluating 'store.getState()').So please help me to solve this error. Thank you for advanced to all.

i changed the react version to and reinstall react-redux.
[React store.getState is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41962033/react-store-getstate-is-not-a-function) i tried this suggestions also. It couldn't work.

```
 reducers/index.js
    let initialStateMarker = {
        markers : []
    }

    const farmLocReducer=(state = initialStateMarker , action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case ADD_FARM_LOC:
                state = Object.assign({}, state, {
                    farmIndex: action.farmIndex
                });
                return state;
            default:
                return state;
        }
        ;
    }


     // this.index.farmLocReducer.farmLocReducer

    const rootReducer = combineReducers({
        farmLocReducer: farmLocReducer,
    })

    export default rootReducer;


    store/index.js
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
    import {createContext} from "react";
    import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

    import rootReducer from '../reducers'; //Import the reducer

    const store = createContext(createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk)));


    export default store;
```

Comment: did you add your store in Provider at the root level of your app?

Comment: Please provide the code written in reducer and store at least.

Comment: @Shan thank you and i edited my question and check it.

Comment: @PremiPrem I didn't see you importing createStore and applyMiddleware from redux. Why are you using context API and redux together? ain't one enough?