# Why I get TypeError: store.getState is not a function

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, redux-saga

could you help me where I wrong?

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import rootReducer from './rootReducer';
import rootSaga from './rootSaga';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const enhancers = compose(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware));


export default (preloadedState) => {
    const store = configureStore({
        reducer: rootReducer,
        middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({ thunk: false }).concat(sagaMiddleware),
        enhancers,
        preloadedState,
    });

    sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
    console.log(store);

    return store;
}
```

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { App } from "./components/App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
    </Provider>
)
```

Comment: where did you use `store.getState`

Comment: nowhere I just import it here

import store from "./store";

    <Provider store={store}>

Comment: You exported a function and forgot to call it!  It should be `import createStore from "./store";  const store = createStore();` See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64448686/10431574